# Hide characters in email address...(asterisk it)

Tags: python

How can I convert/hide characters in the email address
From

```
member@company.org
```

To

```
m****r@c*****y.org
```

I found a package called "email_split", which I could (possibly) use...
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to create asterisk of certain length then you split to add asterisk where due.

Something like this:

```
def ast(length):
    s=""
    for i in range(length):
        s= s + "*"
    return s


s= "member@company.org"
a = s.split("@")
a2 = a[1].split(".")
obs_email= a[0][0] + ast(len(a[0][1:-1])) + a[0][-1] + "@" + a2[0][0] + ast(len(a2[0][1:-1])) + a2[0][-1] + "." + a2[1]
```

Output:

```
'm****r@c*****y.org'
```

Edit: Corrected mistake remarked by @saromba

Comment: Not bad. No regex, thats good...
The character before the @ should not be an asterisk

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Even dots befor the '@' sign and longer or shoter endings (.uk,...) are possible

```
mail = "me.mber@company.org"
at = mail.find('@')
dot = mail[at:].find('.')
mail = mail[0] +'*'*(at-2)+ mail[at-1:at+2]+'*'*(dot-3)+mail[at+dot-1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the portion between first and last character with asterisks.
str indexing and string concat in python is very helpful.

```
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$ cat remthis.py  
def mask_all_in_between_first_and_last(name):
    name = name[0] + '*'*(len(name)-2) + name[-1]
    return name

def mask_email(email):
    username, domain_info = email.split('@')
    domain_name, domain = domain_info.split('.')
    
    username = mask_all_in_between_first_and_last(username)
    domain_name = mask_all_in_between_first_and_last(domain_name)
    return f'{username}@{domain_name}.{domain}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    to_be_masked = 'member@company.org'
    masked = mask_email(to_be_masked)
    print(masked)
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$ python remthis.py 
m****r@c*****y.org
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$
```